# Why is the following "proof" false?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, characteristic-polynomial

### Exercise: Why is the following "proof" false?

$\text{ch}_A(xI-A)=\det(xI-A)$

Substitude $A$ for $x$, and obtain $\det(A-A)=0=\text{ch}_A(A)$.

### Solution: Explanation

We cannot substitude $A$ for $x$ because $A$ is a matrix and $x$ represents a scalar.

$xI$ represents the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
&x\\
&&\ddots\\
&&&x\\
\end{pmatrix}$, and we clearly cannot substitute the matrix $A$ into the entries.

Comment: Is $\operatorname{ch}_A$ supposed to be the characteristic polynomial of $A$? If so, the first expression $\operatorname{ch}_A(xI-A)$ doesn't make any sense. It would make your question more readable if you could write out what false statement is being claimed with this fallacious proof.

Comment: In this problem $x$ is an element of the field, like $\lambda$. Trying to substitute $A$ for $x$ would result in a matrix whose diagonal elements are matrices.

Comment: The other issue is that by your logic, doesn't $ch_A(xI-A)$ also become $ch_A (0)$?